# bower init default values

Tags: bower, bower-install

Is there any way to pass some basic values as argument in bower init command? So that there is no need for manually entering the values. for e.g.

```
bower init --default-params
```

Comment: I realize that right now this functionality is not implemented in bower. Is there any plan to include in future versions?